# ¿Como contar una columna por mes (incluyendo valores nulos), desde el mes actual y solo los 6 meses anteriores a este?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, count

tengo una tabla llamada observacionespersonal, en ella tengo una columna llamada "observaciones" y otra con la fecha de cuando la observación fue creada "created_at", lo que intento es contar cuantas observaciones se han hecho por mes, durante el mes actual y los 6 meses anteriores a este y que si hay un mes que no tiene registros lo cuente con un 0.

Hice esta consulta la cual me cuenta las observaciones realizadas:

```
SELECT COUNT(observaciones) AS observ, 
MONTH(created_at) AS mes
FROM observacionespersonal
WHERE created_at >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH)
GROUP BY mes
```

este es el resultado desde el mes actual y los 6 anteriores:

```
observ  mes 
  1      3
  4      7
  3      8
  1      9
```

lo que intento es que me de un resultado así, desde el mes actual y los 6 anteriores, contando los meses donde no hay regigstros y asignandoles un 0:

```
observ  mes 
  1      3
  0      4
  0      5
  0      6
  4      7
  3      8
  1      9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que considerar el cambio de año, por ejemplo en marzo querrás ver los primeros 3 meses del año actual y los últimos 4 del año anterior.
Entonces sería generar una vista con todos los meses a mostrar y hacer una [*combinación externa*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentencia_JOIN_en_SQL#Combinaci%C3%B3n_externa_(OUTER_JOIN)) con las observaciones agrupadas por año y mes.

```
SELECT ifnull(c.conteo,0) observaciones
     , am.mes
  FROM ( SELECT @m:=@m-1 m
              , year ( current_date - interval @m month) anio
              , month( current_date - interval @m month) mes
           FROM observacionespersonal
              , (SELECT @m:=7) v
           LIMIT 7
       ) am
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT year(created_date) anio
                     , month(created_date) mes
                     , count(observaciones) conteo
                  FROM observacionespersonal
                  WHERE created_at >= cast(date_format(current_date,'%Y-%m-01') as date)-interval 6 month
                  GROUP BY year(created_date)
                         , month(created_date)
              ) c
      ON (c.anio, c.mes) = (am.anio, am.mes)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, y agregar el cambio de año es muy util, no lo iba pensado

Answer (score 2):

Es claro que la consulta que estás haciendo no puede "inventar" información que no existe: si no tienes filas para junio, ese mes será un "hueco", sin embargo, lo que si puedes es generar dinamicamente todos los mes que te interesan (7 meses a partir de hoy hacia atrás) y con estos contar las filas en `observacionespersonal`.

Para generar los meses, y dicho sea de paso, los años de cada uno, podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
select year(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL m.n * -1 MONTH)) as Year,
       month(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL m.n * -1 MONTH)) as Month
       from (Select 0 as n union Select 1  union select 2 union select 3 union 
             select 4 union select 5 union select 6
             ) m
```

Esto puede usarse como base para relacionar con `observacionespersonal`

```
 select p.Year,
        p.Month,
        COUNT(o.observaciones) AS observ
        from (select year(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL m.n * -1 MONTH)) as Year,
                     month(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL m.n * -1 MONTH)) as Month
                     from (Select 0 as n union Select 1  union select 2 union select 3 union 
                            select 4 union select 5 union select 6
                     ) m
        ) p
        left join observacionespersonal o
             on p.Year = year(o.created_at)
             and p.Month = month(o.created_at)
        group by p.Year,
                 p.Month
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, funciona perfectamente, gran punto los años no lo iba pensado

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución diferente (sobre todo en como generar los meses).

Yo prefiero trabajar con fechas y al final agrupar por año y mes.

Para generar el primer día del mes actual y los 6 meses anteriores podrías utilizar una query recursiva (MySql >= 8.0): subquery `meses`.

Luego deberías hacer un `LEFT JOIN` de la subquery `meses` con tu tabla `observacionespersonal` utilizando las fechas para vincular.

Luego agrupar utilizando el año y el mes de la subquery `meses` y contar la cantidad de observaciones:

```
WITH RECURSIVE meses AS (SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AS primer_dia
                         
                         UNION ALL
                         
                         SELECT DATE_ADD(primer_dia, INTERVAL -1 MONTH) AS primer_dia
                         FROM meses 
                         WHERE primer_dia > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -6 MONTH))

SELECT 
      YEAR(m.primer_dia) AS anio,
      MONTH(m.primer_dia) AS mes,
      COUNT(o.observaciones) AS observ 
FROM meses m
LEFT JOIN observacionespersonal o ON o.created_at BETWEEN m.primer_dia AND LAST_DAY(m.primer_dia)
GROUP BY YEAR(m.primer_dia), MONTH(m.primer_dia)
ORDER BY YEAR(m.primer_dia), MONTH(m.primer_dia);
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, otra manera de solucionarlo bastante util

Comment: De nada @Arley!!!